# How to add a notification badge to a Calendar day

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-calendar

Using this library:
https://github.com/Applandeo/Material-Calendar-View

How do I add a notification badge to the selected day?

I can use any other decent library if needed, or Android's own calendar view if it can get the job done.

I want to achieve something like this:
[image: iOS calendar]

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?

Comment: @young_08 none yet.

Comment: @Asim I will check this out: https://github.com/kizitonwose/CalendarView
It says it has custom day view. Promising.
Quite some time passed since your question. Did you find a solution maybe?

Comment: @zsoltvilágos I didn't. I just used the event icon function in the library to create a counter. It doesn't look the same but it gets the job done.

Comment: @PradnyaBhagat I just used Events to show info below the date. Couldn't badge the view.